# exporting a sql view to a csv file

Tags: sql-server, export, csv, sqlcmd, bcp

Whilst I can just about script to pull data via queries, I'm finding it very difficult to figure out how to export the results of a query to a .csv file and save in a network storage location (novice when it comes to the more technical side!).  I've tried various things like the bcp command or using the export wizard or sqlcmd but I can't get anything to work!  I also want to be able to automate the export i.e. run an agent job to create/run this export weekly.
An ex-colleague had set this up but couldn't get it to work.  When I run this:

```sql
USE [DataInsight]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

BEGIN

sqlcmd -S londata01\raisers -d DataInsight -E -s, -W -w 65535 -Q "SET NOCOUNT on; select * from dbo.All_Email_Addresses" -s "," -o "C:\Users\scarsen\Documents\all_emails.csv"

END
```

whereby `londata01\raisers` is the server name, datainsight the DB and all_email addresses a table.  I get

> Incorrect syntax near 'sqlcmd' when run it.

I turned on SQLCMDMode in SSMS and still get this error.

Tried this:

```
bcp "select * from datainsight.dbo.All_Email_Addresses" queryout 'C:\Users\scarsen.csv' –c –t , –S londata01\raisers –T
```

but get Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.

Because I want to automate for a weekly output, I can use an agent job so need to be able to create export within SSMS (I think)

I also tried something that I can't remember using `master..xp_cmdshell` but a message came up saying I didn't have security settings enabled (or similar)

I also tried saving an export via the wizard to an SSIS but get a message saying storing or modifying packages requires runtime and db to the the same version.

In a nutshell, tried lots of things with my limited knowledge but wondered if anyone might be able to help?

Answer (score 3):

bcp is a command-line command utility - you can't call it as a T-SQL command.  However, if you enable `xp_cmdshell`, you can run it via the command-line using this code inside a SQL Server Agent Job (or query window in SQL Server Management Studio):

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000);
SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S londata01\raisers -d DataInsight -E -s, -W -w 65535 -Q "SET NOCOUNT on; select * from dbo.All_Email_Addresses" -s "," -o "C:\Users\scarsen\Documents\all_emails.csv"';
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

In the example above, we're exporting data into the `C:\Users\scarsen\Documents` folder.  In order for this to work from inside SQL Server, the SQL Server Service Account must have access to this folder.

You can enable xp_cmdshell at the server using these T-SQL commands, which you'd run via a query window in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```

You'd only need to enable it once per SQL Server.  In case you want to reverse the above change, simply run this:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
RECONFIGURE;
```

There really is no need to reverse the `show advanced options` configuration setting.  It doesn't have any bearing *at all* on anything other than letting you configure things like `xp_cmdshell`.